# R combine a vector of strings with seq_len

Tags: r, vector, seq

if I have a list of strings, `x`,`y`,`z`. And I wish to combine them with the seq_len, so the list will become: `x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3`. How can I do that? I've tried to use paste, but it's clearly not working. Thanks.

```
a1 = c("x","y","z")
seq_len(3)

paste(a1, seq_len(3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `outer`

```
> c(outer(a1, seq_len(3), paste0))
[1] "x1" "y1" "z1" "x2" "y2" "z2" "x3" "y3" "z3"
```

or `sapply`

```
> c(t(sapply(a1,paste0,seq_len(3))))
[1] "x1" "y1" "z1" "x2" "y2" "z2" "x3" "y3" "z3"
```

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to extract those based on the value inside seq_len? For example, if it's seq_len(3), I want z1 = c("x1","y1","z1"), z2=c("x2","y2","z2"), z3=c("x3","y3","z3"). And if it's seq_len(2), I want z1 = c("x1","y1","z1"), z2=c("x2","y2","z2"). Thanks!

Comment: @SubaruSpirit I don't think you can get vectors like `c("x1","y1","z1")` if you have only `seq_len(2)`, since you don't have additional information to generate the a vector of length 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste0(a1, rep(seq_len(3), each = 3))
# [1] "x1" "y1" "z1" "x2" "y2" "z2" "x3" "y3" "z3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `expand.grid` and `paste`

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(a1, seq_along(a1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `3` directly without retrieving it from your `al` sequence, there is a simple answer:

```r
paste0(a1, gl(3, 3))
# "x1" "y1" "z1" "x2" "y2" "z2" "x3" "y3" "z3"
```